# Problems With Vector Reflection with Particle Collisions

Tags: javascript, html, math, three.js

I was wondering whether I made a math mistake in my particle collision simulation found [here](http://jsbin.com/quqega/37/edit).

The particles don't seem to separate properly during collision resolution. Here is a code snippet from the function which separates particles and changes their velocities:

```
//particle 1
var pi = particles[i];
//particle 2
var pj = particles[j];

//particle 1 to particle 2
var pimpj = pi.mesh.position.clone().sub(pj.mesh.position); 
//particle 2 to particle 1
var pjmpi = pj.mesh.position.clone().sub(pi.mesh.position); 
//if colliding (radius is 20)
if(pimpj.length() < 20 && pimpj.length() != 0) 
{


    //reflect velocity off of 1->2
    pi.velocity = pi.velocity.reflect(pimpj.clone().normalize()).multiplyScalar(restitution);
    //reflect velocity off of 2->1 
    pj.velocity = pj.velocity.reflect(pjmpi.clone().normalize()).multiplyScalar(restitution);

    //move particle 1 to appropiate location based off of distance in between
    var pip = pi.velocity.clone().normalize().multiplyScalar(20-pimpj.length());
    //move particle 2 
    var pjp = pj.velocity.clone().normalize().multiplyScalar(20-pimpj.length());
    pi.mesh.position.add(pip);
    pj.mesh.position.add(pjp);
}
```

I have tried reversing pimpj with pjmpi while changing pi.velocity, but to no effect.

note: I am using **three.js**

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the particle collisions you seem to be looking for are [Elastic collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision), for which there is maths covering the calculation of the velocities after a collision.

The collision is simplest in the centre of momentum frame, so if you first calculate that frame **V** = (m<sub>1</sub>**v<sub>1</sub>** + m<sub>2</sub>**v<sub>2</sub>**)/(m<sub>1</sub>+m<sub>2</sub>), then you can subtract it from both particles, do a simple symmetric collision and add the frame velocity back on afterwards.

From there, calculate the velocities using the formulae [in the 2 & 3d section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-_and_three-dimensional) of that page.

Specific points on your code:

1. `pimpj` = -`pjmpi`, so you don't need both
2. A collision occurs when the *paths* between the last frame and this frame got too close; if you only check the distance at each frame you will have problems where particles fly through each other at high speed, and that you have to keep shifting their positions because they are already overlapping when you detect the collision.
3. Ideally calculate the positions on impact and use those to redirect them.
4. For speed, only calculate `pimpj.clone().normalize()` once, and store it - you're not changing this direction unit vector later, so you don't need to keep recalculating it, or calculating pjmpi-derived equivalents (see #1)

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the problem is that your model of collision is overly simplistic. The basic rules for collision are conservation of momentum and conservation of energy. Looking at the 1D case. If both particles have the same mass m and u1 and u2 are you velocities beforehand and v1, v2 are the velocities after then

```
m u1 + m2 u2 = m v1 + m v2
```

conservation of energy for a perfect collision gives

```
1/2 m u1.u1 + 1/2 m u2.u2 = 1/2 m v1.v1 + 1/2 m v2.v2.
```

These two equations have the solution v1 = u2, v2 = u1. That is the velocities switch. In particular if one velocity is zero before collision then after collision the other velocity becomes zero after the collision.  You can see this happen when using a newton's cradle.

In 2D we can resolve in a coordinate system with 1 direction along to the plane of contact and one direction perpendicular to it. The force only occurs in the perpendicular direction, this means the velocities along the pane don't change but the perpendicular velocities switch.

```
var u = pjmpi.clone().normalize();
var v = new THREE.Vector3(u.y,-u.x,0);

// resolve in two directions

var piu = pi.velocity.dot(u);
var piv = pi.velocity.dot(v);

pi.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
    pju * u.x + piv * v.x, 
    pju * u.y + piv * v.y, 
    0);

pj.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
    piu * u.x + pjv * v.x, 
    piu * u.y + pjv * v.y, 
    0);
```

That works for a perfectly elastic collision. See [Wikipedia elastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-Dimensional_Collision_With_Two_Moving_Objects) which has an nice illustration. The formula at the end simplifies a bit if you take the masses equal.

For an partially inelastic collision with restitution R we can look at the end of http://www.plasmaphysics.org.uk/collision2d.htm. Now take the velocity of the center of mass w. This will not change after the collision because the total momentum is conserved. So w=(u1+u2)/2 = (v1+v2)/2. Take the velocities relative to this center of mass
v1' = v1-w, v2' = v2-w, apply the restitution v1'' = R (v1'-w), v2'' = R(v2'-w) and add the velocity of the center of mass.

```
  v1''' = R(v1-v2)/2 + (v1+v2)/2 
  v2''' = R(v1-v2)/2 + (v1+v2)/2
```

Also see wikipedia [Inelastic collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inelastic_collision) which has the same formula in 1D.

This translate to code as

```
var u = pjmpi.clone().normalize();
var v = new THREE.Vector3(u.y,-u.x,0);

// resolve in two directions
var piu = pi.velocity.dot(u);
var piv = pi.velocity.dot(v);
var pju = pj.velocity.dot(u);
var pjv = pj.velocity.dot(v);

// velocities after collision
var v1x = pju * u.x + piv * v.x;
var v1y = pju * u.y + piv * v.y;

var v2x = piu * u.x + pjv * v.x; 
var v2y = piu * u.y + pjv * v.y;

// vel center of mass
var wx = (v1x+v2x)/2;                
var wy = (v1y+v2y)/2;

// difference
var dx = (v1x-v2x)/2;
var dy = (v1y-v2y)/2;

// final velocities
pi.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
    wx + restitution * dx,
    wy + restitution * dy,
    0);

pj.velocity = new THREE.Vector3(
    wx - restitution * dx,
    wy - restitution * dy,
    0);

// We can print the KE and momentum before and after to check     
console.log("KE before ",
   pi.velocity.lengthSq()+pj.velocity.lengthSq());
console.log("M before ",
   pi.velocity.x+pj.velocity.x ,
   pi.velocity.y+pj.velocity.y);
console.log("KE after",v1x*v1x+v1y*v1y + v2x*v2x + v2y*v2y); 
console.log("M after ", v1x+v2x, v1y+v2y);
console.log("KE rest",
    pi.velocity.lengthSq()+pj.velocity.lengthSq());
console.log("M rest ",
    pi.velocity.x+pj.velocity.x , 
    pi.velocity.y+pj.velocity.y);
```

This can simplify nicely. Start by taking the mean and half the difference of the two particles. Reflect the difference and apply the restitution

```
var len = pjmpi.length();
// unit vector normal to plane of collision
var nx = pjmpi.x / len;
var ny = pjmpi.y / len;
// unit vector tangent to plane of collision
var tx = -ny;
var ty = nx;
// center of mass
var wx = (pi.velocity.x+pj.velocity.x)/2;
var wy = (pi.velocity.y+pj.velocity.y)/2;
// half difference
var dx = (pi.velocity.x-pj.velocity.x)/2;
var dy = (pi.velocity.y-pj.velocity.y)/2;
// resolve in two directions
var a = dx * nx + dy * ny;
var b = dx * tx + dy * ty;
// reflect difference in normal
var cx = -a * nx + b * tx;
var cy = -a * ny + b * ty;
// apply restitution and add back center of mass                                
pi.velocity.set(
    wx + restitution * cx,
    wy + restitution * cy,
    0);
pj.velocity.set(
    wx - restitution * cx,
    wy - restitution * cy,
    0);
```

I've used THREE as little as possible to avoid creating too many objects.

I've saved this as a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/8axnL59k/. I've reduced number of points, and removed gravity to make things a bit simpler to see.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the very good points in the other answers, you only want to do the velocity changes if the particles move towards each other. This is the case of the derivative of the distance is negative, which can be transformed to the scalar product of `pi-pj` and `vi-vj` being negative.

Without that you may enter an infinite loop where the velocities get reflected back and forth while the distance stays below the critical radius.